# how to access logged in user in a model in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp-1.2

Ive already pasted this to my app model

```
    function getCurrentUser() {
       // for CakePHP 1.x:
       App::import('Component','Session');
       $Session = new SessionComponent();
       $user = $Session->read('Auth.User');
       return $user;
    }
```

and also pasted this to my model

```
   $user = $this->getCurrentUser();
   $user_id = $user['id'];
```

so that i can use the $user_id in my query like this..

```
 "SELECT * FROM LOGS WHERE user_id=$user_id"
```

but i always get this error

```
 parse error, expecting `T_FUNCTION'
```

Comment: First of all, **do NOT compose a query like this by adding the $user_id without escaping** CakePHP will NOT escape it's value if constructing a query manually. Use something like this: `$this->Log->find('all', array('conditions' => array('user_id' => $user_id));` where $this->Log is your 'Log' model

Comment: Second, as far as I can see, the error you're describing is *not* in the code you posted. Please add the code surrounding the code you've posted, or try to debug it yourself, it seems to be you've forgot to put a quote or semicolon somewhere

Comment: thank you for responding. I already solved it though.
    $logs=$this->Log->find('all', array('conditions' => array('assigned_by' => $this->Auth->user('id'))));

I just accessed it in my controller.